# How do I make a dropdown that changes my options for my other dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, css

What i'm focusing on now is having a dropdown for my other dropdowns shown, and I want what we'll call my "master dropdown" to change the items in my sub dropdowns.

(background to better understand)
I'm new to js
I'm trying to make a workout card, the master dropdown is going to be the selector to choose which muscle group the user is doing for the day,
if the user selects chest & tri I want there to be workouts the user can select from when they select "chest" from the master dropdown, 
and when the user selects triceps in the other master dropdown, I want the tricep workouts to show up. so for the particular muscle group that the user selects, only the workouts for that muscle group shows up, so if the user selects shoulders, I don't want squats or deadlifts to show up etc.
 here's my rusty code so far

```
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scratch.css">

<header>


</header>
<body>
<h1>SNAP YA MF WORKOUT & SEND TO YA HOMIES!</h1>
<table id="first">
<tr>
    <th>Lift</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>no idea</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dropdown</td>
    <td>dropdown</td>
    <td>dropdown</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dropdown</td>
    <td>dropdown</td>
    <td>dropdown</td>

</tr>
</table>
 <div id = t1button> <button onclick="myFunction()">+</button></div>
 <div id = t1pre> <button onclick="preFunction()">-</button></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var table = document.getElementById("first");

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var td2 = document.createElement("td");
var td3 = document.createElement("td");
var txt = document.createTextNode("dropdown");
var txt2 = document.createTextNode("dropdown");
var txt3 = document.createTextNode("dropdown");


td.appendChild(txt);
tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);

td2.appendChild(txt2);
tr.appendChild(td2);
table.appendChild(tr);

td3.appendChild(txt3);
tr.appendChild(td3);
table.appendChild(tr);

}
function deleteRow() {
var row = 
}
</script>

<table id="second">
<tr>
    <th>Lift</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>no idea</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dropdown</td>
    <td>dropdown</td>
    <td>dropdown</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dropdown</td>
    <td>dropdown</td>
    <td>dropdown</td>

</tr>
</table>







</body>
</html>


table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

 td, th {
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}


#first, #second{
text-align: center;
display: inline;
margin: 0 auto;

} 
#t1button{
position: wrap;
```

Comment: You may have decent luck if you have all of the dropdowns built and then just use javascript/css to show/hide the sub lists as needed instead of trying to change the options in the dropdowns. Changing the options can also have some buggy behavior when items are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is to update the select options as per the selected option.

The great idea of resolving this problem is to create the two select boxes and show the options in the second select box based on the first one.

```
 <select name="select1" id="select1">
     <option value="">Please select the option</option>
     <option value="lift">Lift</option>
     <option value="weight">Weight</option>
     <option value="chest">Chest</option>
 </select>

 <select name="select2" id="select2" disabled="disabled">
     <option value="">Sub Options</option>
 </select>

 $(document).ready(function () {
     var options = {
         'lift' : {
             'lift-dropdown1' : 'Lift Dropdown 1',
             'lift-dropdown2' : 'Lift Dropdown 2',
             'lift-dropdown3' : 'Lift Dropdown 3',
         },
         'weight' : {
             'weight-dropdown1' : 'Weight Dropdown 1',
             'weight-dropdown2' : 'Weight Dropdown 2',
             'weight-dropdown3' : 'Weight Dropdown 3',
         },
         'chest' : {
             'chest-dropdown1' : 'Chest Dropdown 1',
             'chest-dropdown2' : 'Chest Dropdown 2',
             'chest-dropdown3' : 'Chest Dropdown 3',
         },
     };

     $('#select1').on('change', function () {
          var $el = $("#select2");
          $el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          var selectedOption = $(this).val();
          $el.empty(); // remove old options
          $.each(options[selectedOption], function(key,value) {
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
               .attr("value", value).text(key));
          });
          $el.removeAttr('disabled');
     })
 });
```

Also, you can refer the running code from here https://jsfiddle.net/Sakshigargit15/4um3fqt8/11/

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for!